# What are some fast growing bonsai fruit trees in Delhi?

Tags: fruit-trees, bonsai

I am looking for a fruit tree which I can make into a bonsai, but I have a lack of patience. Please suggest a fast growing tree in Delhi environment that could easily be bonsai.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the fruit produced from this tree? If so, do you mean bonsai (which won't fruit), or do you mean trained into a small form, such as espalier or fan trained, outdoors?

Comment: Bonsai can fruit, but it takes a while for a small tree to mature enough to support fruit bearing. However for the original question, bonsai is not suitable if you want to bear fruit, in which case bamboo is 100% correct. You probably want a fruit tree on a dwarfing root stock.

Answer (score 6):

A bit unconventional, but if you want something that will grow quickly, train well & produce beautiful flowers and fruit with proper care, you could try a chili plant. [fatalii.net](http://www.fatalii.net/bonsai_chiles_bonchi) has some wonderful examples of chili plants trained like bonsai. Scroll down his page for info on growing & more photos.

**Bolivian Rainbow Chili Bonsai**
[image]

**EDIT:**

Results like some of those on his website can be achieved in less than a year & the plants, if taken care of well, can live for many many years!

If something like that is not appealing to you, Mulberries are sometimes used for bonsai & are relatively fast growing (perhaps the white mulberry "[Morus alba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morus_alba)" would be a good choice).

For the quickest results, you would want to [collect a reasonably grown wild specimen](http://www.bonsai4me.com/AdvTech/ATcollectring%20trees%20from%20the%20wild%20W%20Pall.htm), or purchase one locally rather than grow from seed.

**White Mulberry Bonsai**
[image]

Comment: I had some more thoughts on this answer later on & have edited the original answer with more detail.

Comment: The mulberry sounds interesting to me, though I would pick black or red myself for more tasty berries.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on several mulberry white and black when one plant I collected the parent plant over 30 years old had several stalks rooted and had leaves that were attached to the main stump I quickly cut them away and planted them now the are fruit bearing mini trees like a tiny orchard ..very happy I collected my own specimen..